# NSObject class conforms to protocol contained in NSArray with Swift

Tags: swift, nsarray, protocols, swift2, swift-array

I would like to create a method in Swift that returns an array of NSObject objects that conform to a protocol.
I've tried something like this:

```
func createManagers() -> [Manager] {
    let result = NSMutableArray(capacity: self.classes.count)
    (self.classes as NSArray).enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (object: AnyObject!, idx: Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        // TODO: do something and fill the result array
    }
    return result as NSArray as! [Manager]
}
```

`Manager` is a protocol as you see. I am receiving the error that the cast at the return statement will always fail.
I want to tell the compiler that I have an array of objects of NSObject type and all elements conform to Manager protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to write Objective-C in Swift. Move away from `NSObject`, `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.

Here is your code without any Objective-C types:

```
func createManagers() -> [Manager] {
    let result = [Manager]()
    for (index, aClass) in classes.enumerate() {
        // TODO: do something and fill the result array
    }
    return result
}
```

If you want to ensure your return types are a subclass of `NSObject`:

```
func createManagers<T: NSObject where T: Manager>() -> [T] {
    var result = [T]()
    for (index, aClass) in classes.enumerate() {
        // TODO: do something and fill the result array
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: <T: NSObject where T: Manager>, can you please point me to the documentation where I can read more about this? Thank you!

Comment: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html) is the documentation on Swift generics.

Answer (score 0):

Your return type is a Dictionary with key NSObject and value type Manager, instead of an array. Change the return type to `[Manager]`. Also you probably want to use the `map` function of array:

```
func createManagers() -> [Manager] {
    return classes.map { doSomethingAndTransformIntoManager($0) }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I am going to edit my question. This is the one I've tried for the first time, but this doesn't work. I want to tell the compiler that I have an array of objects of NSObject type and all elements conform to Manager protocol.